How to Provide Runtime Parameters to a Custom Annotation's Interceptor in a Jakarta EE Project?
I'm working on a Jakarta EE project where I have a custom annotation and an associated interceptor. The annotation is used to execute some logic, and it works as expected as a standalone. However, I need to pass a runtime value (specifically, the result of userContext.getUserId()) to the interceptor when the annotated method is invoked.
Here's a simplified version of my setup:
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class MyClass {
    @Inject
    private UserContext userContext;
    
    @MyLog
    public void myMethod() {
        // Method logic
    }
}

The @MyLog annotation and the interceptor are defined in dependency A, which does not have access to dependency B, which provides the UserContext. MyClass however has both dependencies, A and B.
My questions are:

I understand that annotations in Java can generally only accept constant values. Is there a way to pass the result of userContext.getUserId() as a parameter to the annotation at runtime?
If not, what would be a recommended approach to pass or inject such runtime-dependent data into the interceptor, if possible?

I'm looking for a solution that fits well within the Jakarta EE framework. Any guidance or examples would be greatly appreciated!
I initially tried to pass the userContext.getUserId() directly to the annotation like this:
@MyLog(userContext.getUserId())
public void myMethod() {
    // Method logic
}

I was hoping this would allow the userContext.getUserId() value to be passed as an annotation value and then used by the interceptor at runtime. However, I realized that annotations in Java can only accept constant values, so this approach didn't work.

Do you have control over the implementation of MyLogInterceptor and the code in "dependency A" in general? Aside of that, you can rule out option (1) "pass [...] a parameter to the annotation at runtime", it is not possible.

Following Solution worked for my problem:

MyLog + MyInterceptor are defined in Dependency A
UserContext is defined in Dependency B
Dependency A and B don't have access to each other
MyClass is a class in a Project that has both Dependency A and B

A Solution that worked for me was Implementing a ContextHolder in Dependency A.
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class MyContextHolder implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2L;

    private static final ThreadLocal<String> userIdHolder = new ThreadLocal<>();

    public static void setUserId(final String userId) {
        userIdHolder.set(userId);
    }

    public static String getUserId() {
        return userIdHolder.get();
    }
}

Aditionally I created a new annotation @Contextualize in the same Project as MyClass, which uses an interceptor to set the UserId in the ContextHolder (make sure that the @Contextualize0 Annotation has a higher (lower number) priority than the @MyLog Annotation).
public class MyClass {
    @Contextualize
    @MyLog
    public void myMethod() {
        // do Something
    }
}


You can achieve your goal by accessing the UserContext instance directly within the interceptor. Below is an approach to accomplish this:
Define the @MyLog annotation:
@InterceptorBinding
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MyLog {
}

Create the Interceptor:
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.interceptor.AroundInvoke;
import javax.interceptor.Interceptor;
import javax.interceptor.InvocationContext;

@MyLog
@Interceptor
public class MyLogInterceptor {

    @Inject
    private UserContext userContext;

    @AroundInvoke
    public Object logMethodInvocation(InvocationContext context) throws Exception {
        String userId = userContext.getUserId();
        System.out.println("User ID: " + userId);
        
        // Proceed with method invocation
        return context.proceed();
    }
}

Ensure your interceptor is enabled:
In beans.xml, enable the interceptor:
<beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd">

    <interceptors>
        <class>com.example.MyLogInterceptor</class>
    </interceptors>

</beans>

In the MyClass example, leave the annotation as is. The interceptor will automatically have access to the UserContext since it is injected, and it will be invoked whenever the @MyLog-annotated method myMethod is called.
The MyClass remains unchanged:
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class MyClass {
    @Inject
    private UserContext userContext;
    
    @MyLog
    public void myMethod() {
        // Method logic
    }
}


Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, the solution doesn't work for me, because the interceptor can't access the dependency providing the UserContext and therefore can't inject it. The required parameter needs to be provided externally from MyClass.
If you have another approach, I'd appreciate it.
